# Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS with minimal hassle

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, ubuntu-studio

I've been a Ubuntu user since 12.04 LTS, but only as a secondary install to my normal Windows usage. (Actually, if I still could, I'd prefer AmigaOS...) One thing which I've come to dread is the regular major upgrades; I still haven't even found a concise way of getting a list of my currently installed software so that I can reinstall!

I recently upgraded my laptop's secondary boot from 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu Studio 20.04, and I like it. I like it a lot, since I do a fair bit of analog media conversions and so forth. I'm still trying to remember everything which was installed on the laptop before so I can reinstall, but I seldom use that computer as a Linux machine so there wasn't a whole lot to lose (and I do make regular backups of my personal files!).

I'm wanting to upgrade the desktop machine where I run 18.04 LTS the same way. However, I've got a lot more work and programs on that machine; actually on that one Linux is primary and the Windows 7 install is "just hangin' around" (I have an older Full Retail Box Win7 home which Microsoft wouldn't upgrade and, since I can use it on any computer [one at a time], I keep it around for compatibility with older games and such). What's the best way for running this upgrade on this machine (AMD FX-4100 Quad, 8 GB RAM) with the least hassle to getting back to my current setup and application programs?

@guiverc, my actual Ubuntu installed version on the desktop is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, NOT Ubuntu Studio. I had never used Studio before until I installed it on my laptop; it made my Presonus Audiobox USB sound interface usable under Linux for the first time...one reason I want to install it on my desktop as well when I upgrade. But no, I currently have none of the Studio functionality on the desktop. I'm just at the point where I'm ready to move to the newest major release upgrade and I'd like to incorporate Studio when I do so. I'm asking for ways to minimize the trouble and inconvenience on the way. Thanks.

Comment: You can try `dpkg -l`.

Comment: What was your actual 18.04 install?   Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** an LTS release, it had *extended* support available which required the use of a PPA, however they (*Ubuntu Studio*) have published instructions that it should be purged prior to upgrade to 20.04 to avoid complications. Are you using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu Studio 18.04 ?  Do you have already, or or are you wanting to add Ubuntu Studio to the base Ubuntu (GNOME) desktop?  https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/ etc

Answer (score 1):

I see two options to get to an Ubuntu Studio 20.04 installation:

### Install a fresh new Ubuntu Studio 20.04

This would be my recommended way.

- Make a list of the software you are using regularly, so you can easily add it afterwards if it is not already installed.
- Backup your home directory and any other personal data you have on the machine.
- Think about if and how you want to partition your drives, and if you want encryption.
- Write an Ubuntu Studio 20.04 image to a USB drive and go for it.

**Advantage:** You can be sure you have a clean and proper OS without any dependency issues. If you find you're missing an application, you can always install it afterwards.

**Disadvantage:** You will have to reinstall any applications that are missing from the base OS yourself, backup your personal data before, and will probably have to spend some time to tweak the configuration to your liking.

### Upgrade your existing installation

Alternatively, you could upgrade your existing Ubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04, and then install the [Ubuntu Studio installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer) to add the Ubuntu Studio parts. I have never done it this way and cannot testify as to how well that works, or how it differs to a fresh Ubuntu Studio install.

**Advantage:** This should keep all your existing applications and personal data, as long as they are still compatible with 20.04.

**Disadvantage:** You risk dependency issues or issues with applications that are no longer supported in 20.04.

Personally, I keep a spreadsheet with all the software I installed on top of the original OS image, as well as all custom configurations I did and pitfalls to avoid. There seems to be no tool available that tells you which packages a certain user installed manually after the OS was installed, so you have to keep track yourself.